# Excluding data rows if 2 rows have data matching in 2 columns

Tags: sql, impala, hue

Set Up: data is stored on hadoop and queries in Impala.

I'm trying to create a query that allows me to get a breakdown of the delivery we are seeing from our clients (their delivery being a count of all the rows we have seen in our database, for a given period. In order to do this, I need to exclude where we have double counted on a row, so instead of the 2+ rows being counted, we just count the 1.

A double count in this instance is where 2 columns have the exact same row data.

Example: In the table below I should be able to run a query so I remove row 1 from my count on "C4" as the first 2 rows have the 2 columns matching.

```
TABLE = table
c1 = string
c2 = bigint

C1    || C2         || C3  || C4
--------------------------
a     || 1          || a   || 1
a     || 1          || a   || 1
a     || 2          || b   || 1
a     || 3          || a   || 1
a     || 4          || b   || 1
b     || 2          || c   || 1
c     || 1          || d   || 1
c     || 2          || d   || 1
```

Current Query that returns all rows:

```
SELECT c1,
       c3,
       count(c4) AS 'delivery'
FROM table
WHERE c1 = 'a'
GROUP BY c1, c3
```

From what I have checked online I need to create a sub query to identify these rows however I haven't had any luck doing this correctly and entered a rabbit hole, where I tried to create a new row that combines the 2 columns like below:

```
SELECT
        UNIQUE = c2 + cast(c1 as BIGINT)
FROM table
WHERE month = month(now())
```

From this new row I was then going to just review the rows that were unique but I'm sure there is probably a similar way to achieve the result I m aiming for.

From the above table example I would aim to see the below results:

```
c1     c3      delivery
a      a       2
a      b       1
```

Grateful for any recommendations you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions.  For the unique rows:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1, c2 ORDER BY c1) as seqnum
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

For aggregation:

```
SELECT t.c1, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1, c2 ORDER BY c1) as seqnum
      FROM t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY c1;
```

If the latter is what you want, you can also use:

```
SELECT c1, COUNT(DISTINCT c2)
FROM t
GROUP BY c1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gordon, 

I've tried both options 

no 1 is returning an error relating to the "group". I've tried this bit in other rows and failed. Here is what I'm currently trying:

SELECT c1,
       c3,
       count(*) AS 'delivery'
FROM table;
GROUP BY c1, c3
FROM (SELECT tabe.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c1, c2 ORDER BY c1) as seqnum
      FROM table
     ) able
WHERE c1 = 'a' AND seqnum = 1

no 2 doesn't match up with my comparison. Would it only be returning based on if c2 is distinct, as opposed to if the combination of c1+c2 is distinct?